# Set Filter Hue Rotate To A PNG Image in CSS3

Tags: css, filter

I'm trying to set a `hue-rotate(90deg)` filter to a png image. But it changes just background-color. How can I change the image color via `hue-rotate`?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sundowatch/b42dLv5q/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through it

```css
img{width: 100px;height: 50px;mix-blend-mode:lighten;background:#fff;margin-bottom:-5px;}
.red{ background-color: #f00;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <img src="http://truncgil.com.tr/pillow1-main.png">
</div>
```

Comment: But it converts all parts of image to red. I want to convert just existing part of image